# how to prevent user from submitting the same form twice

Tags: python, django

I have the codes below in my views and models. But I want a situation in which a  user cannot submit the same form twice. once a user submits the form he or she can only see a preview of what has been submitted but is unable to submit the same form.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
#views.py
def index(request):
    form = MembershipForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = MembershipForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect("home")
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form)


#models.py
class Membership(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.IntegerField(default='0',blank=True, null=True)
    department = models.IntegerField(default='0',blank=True, null=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.fullname)
```

Comment: Record some sort of session flag/cookie that means "has already filled out this form". Check for that when requesting the form, and if set, just return the preview.

Comment: The redirect after a successful post should prevent t users from submitting the same form twice

Comment: How is the user submitting the same form twice?  Are they clicking the Back button after submitting the first time?

Comment: Iain Shelvington if I redirect the user after a successful post once the user login again the form will appear for him/ her to fill and submit again. John Gordon, what I meant was that, after a successful post once the user login into the application again he or she shouldn't be able to fill and make another post.  @larsks, your write-up sounds like that is exactly what I want but if you can help me with a sample code I would be very grateful. Thank you guys for your help I appreciate your contributions.

Comment: If you want each user have one membership you need a `OneToOne` relation between them.

Comment: In your models there is no way to know which user add a membership in your db. Need to change your models